# Add Timeline for extracting tweets using R

Tags: r, twitter, web-scraping

I was exploring different methods of extracting tweets with **R**

I used this:

```
library("twitteR")
library("ROAuth")

download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem",destfile="cacert.pem")

#create an object "cred" that will save the authenticated object that we can use for later sessions
    cred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    consumerSecret='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    requestURL='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
    accessURL='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
    authURL='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize')

# Executing the next step generates an output --> To enable the connection, please direct your web browser to: <hyperlink> . Note:  You only need to do this part once
    cred$handshake(cainfo="cacert.pem")

load("twitter authentication.Rdata")
registerTwitterOAuth(cred)

search.string <- "#GoT"
no.of.tweets <- 100

tweets <- searchTwitter(search.string, n=no.of.tweets, cainfo="cacert.pem",lang="en")

tweets
```

But I can only retrieve `tweets` for a single month

So i needed a way to add `timeline` between the code, so that I can extract tweets from past `2-3` years...

Answer (score 0):

That's a limitation of the Twitter Search API.

https://twittercommunity.com/t/new-limit-on-search-api-to-limit-tweets-less-than-a-week-please-help-is-there-any-way-to-search-tweets-with-a-hashtag-that-is-older-than-2-weeks/7710

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @zx8754 As I understand, it means "You can not do it, and here's why:". So it is an answer. Although, it lacks a citation from Twitter Search API.

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, the [Twitter Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) only provides access to Tweets up to around 7 days old, and is optimised for recency / may not be a complete index.

You have two options:

1. Open a connection to the [Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview) and listen for references to your search term using a filter. This will not allow you to search backwards, but will let you listen on that term going forwards.
2. Pay for access to the complete Twitter data index via [Gnip](http://gnip.com). This is a commercial enterprise option and therefore may not suit you.

Apart from that, you'll have to live within the limitations and rate limits of the public API.

Comment: thanks for the info!
I had one more question about extracting tweets, since Twitter API is only providing us tweets from past one week, is there any way I can get tweets- store it in a database? 
A "Link" to a website may be helpful!
Thanks in advance!